# extract information from whoistext

Tags: php

i am getting who is data a text, now i want to extract information like Admin   Phone ,Expiration Date , Address etc .   the  text i am getting is shown below:

```
$text ="Access to .IN WHOIS information is provided to assist persons in determining    the contents of a domain name registration record in the .IN registry database. The data in this record is provided by .IN Registry for informational purposes only, and .IN does not guarantee its accuracy. This service is intended only for query-based access. You agree that you will use this data only for lawful purposes and that, under no circumstances will you use this data to: (a) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission by e-mail, telephone, or facsimile of mass unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations to entities other than the data recipient's own existing customers; or (b) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that send queries or data to the systems of Registry Operator, a Registrar, or Afilias except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or modify existing registrations. All rights reserved. .IN reserves the right to modify these terms at any time. By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy. Domain ID:D21089-AFIN Domain Name:GOOGLE.IN Created On:14-Feb-2005 20:35:14 UTC Last Updated On:25-Jul-2012 23:14:22 UTC Expiration Date:14-Feb-2013 20:35:14 UTC Sponsoring Registrar:Mark Monitor (R84-AFIN) Status:CLIENT DELETE PROHIBITED Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED Status:CLIENT UPDATE PROHIBITED Registrant ID:EPPIPM-143349 Registrant Name:Admin DNS Registrant Organization:GOOGLE INC. Registrant Street1:1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Registrant Street2: Registrant Street3: Registrant City:Mountain View, CA Registrant State/Province: Registrant Postal Code:94043 Registrant Country:US Registrant Phone: +1.6503300100  Registrant Phone Ext.: Registrant FAX: Registrant FAX Ext.: Registrant Email:dns-admin@google.com Admin ID:EPPIPM-143349 Admin Name:Admin DNS Admin Organization:GOOGLE INC. Admin Street1:1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Admin Street2: Admin Street3: Admin City:Mountain View, CA Admin State/Province: Admin Postal Code:94043 Admin Country:US Admin Phone: +1.6503300100  Admin Phone Ext.: Admin FAX: Admin FAX Ext.: Admin Email:dns-admin@google.com Tech ID:EPPIPM-143349 Tech Name:Admin DNS Tech Organization:GOOGLE INC. Tech Street1:1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Tech Street2: Tech Street3: Tech City:Mountain View, CA Tech State/Province: Tech Postal Code:94043 Tech Country:US Tech Phone: +1.6503300100  Tech Phone Ext.: Tech FAX: Tech FAX Ext.: Tech Email:dns-admin@google.com Name Server:NS1.GOOGLE.COM Name Server:NS2.GOOGLE.COM Name Server:NS3.GOOGLE.COM Name Server:NS4.GOOGLE.COM Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: Name Server: DNSSEC:Unsigned ";
```

please  help me to get the data.

Comment: sir, iget the  data  from whois server  but the data is  as text,  now  how to retrieve the information  from the text ,  text is the data for sample

Comment: SO is no "give me code" service ... you could try to use regular expressions to get the desired data from that string ...

Answer (score 1):

You are best off using `PEAR::Net_Whois` which is a whois package written in PHP to do exactly that. Find it at http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Whois